# Unable to configure Tensorflow in GPU after upgrading using pip install?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have upgraded my tensorflow from 0.10 to 0.11, but my tensorflow seem to use only the CPU when I run this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Creates a graph.
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print sess.run(c)
```

I have tried to use './configure' on the root directory of tensorflow, but afterwards the GPU is still not enabled. Must I uninstall the whole of tensorflow to use the GPU again?

Comment: The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) list different pip sources for different versions where only some of them support GPU's. Maybe you selected the wrong one (or this was done automatically). Just set the right environment-var to some gpu-version and install it again.

Comment: If you want to use the one from sources, just build the [pip package](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources) and re-install. Running configure just sets up the build, but doesn't build nor installs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed the docs instruction, and I'm using the GPU now.